# Edit document in document array from .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need a way to get values and edit the values of an array returned by .find() example:

```
$container = $('#survey-types');
$slider = $container.find('#slide-container');
$slides = $slider.find('.slide');
for(let i = 0; i < $slides.length; i++){
    console.log($slides[i].width());
}
```

But this gives me `.width() is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$slides[i]` is an `HTMLElement`, not `jQuery` wrapper, and `HTMLElement` does not have a `width()` method. Try replacing `$slides[i]` with `$slides.eq(i)`:

```
for(let i = 0; i < $slides.length; i++){
    console.log($slides.eq(i).width());
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. When I'm able to select it as the answer I will.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jQuery `each()` method, rather than writing your own for loop.

```
$slides.each(function(index, slide){
    console.log($(slide).width());
    //or you could still use eq
    console.log($slides.eq(index).width());
});
```